# "Neee" instead of one's name or before his name -- what does this mean?

Tags: meaning, slang, idioms, casual

When someone - my friend - says "neeee" to me, what does it mean? It's not when I say something and they respond "neeee" or "sou da yo neee". It's when "neee" is used either by itself, or instead of my name or before my name, for instance "neee, Maiku, doushita no?" or "neeee, choytto matte".

What does "neee" mean in such situations?

Answer (score 5):

ねえ said in isolation is an interjection that means one of the followings:

- Yeah; That's right; I agree; You can say that (pronounced ねえ{HH} with a flat tone)

  - [What does the long "neeeeee" (ねー) mean when 2 friends are talking?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52346/5010)
- Hey; Listen; Say (ねえ{HL}; sometimes repeated ねえねえ{HLHL})

  - [Is interjection ねえ、ねえ gender agnostic?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47343/5010)
- Please; Come on (ねえ{HL})

In your case, it's the second usage as a simple attention drawer.

Comment: and the 3rd one too

Comment: In a way it's like how in English "Hey" is used to grab someone's attention, and can also be used to say "Hello". In this case, ねえ is to seek someone's attention as naruto explained